# jQuery document ready - function calls: sequential or asynch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, asynchronous, onload

I recognise this question probably goes to how Javascript functions operate in general (and not just my particular case), but...

I want to know how my document ready function... umm... functions. In stylised form, it's like the following:

```
$(function () {
    object1.init();
    object2.init();
    object3.init(); etc...
```

Will object2.init() only fire when object1.init() returns? Or will they all fire in an asynchronous kind of way?

UPDATE: If they fire sequentially, is there any way I can get them to go simultaneously (which I possibly don't need to do)?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to make them  fire simultaneously . Not just jQuery, but javascript doesn't support parallel programming.

Comment: @gdoron  Thanks for adding this. I'm right in thinking that closures can keep running while the main train rolls on, though, right? For example, an animation will keep running long after the function has moved on to the next lines of code.

Comment: Nope, one line of code at a time. The thing is with the animations functions is they're using `setTimeout` so they are not locking the working thread. But it's still one operation at a time.

Comment: Take a look on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nT29h/). Watch how the second function wait for the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will object2.init() only fire when object1.init() returns? Or will they all fire in an asynchronous kind of way?

object2.init() only fire when object1.init() returns.
All the functions are stored in a queue, and get fired one after the other.

There is no way to make them fire simultaneously.
Not just jQuery, but javascript doesn't support parallel programming.

---

**You can see the jQuery source code:**

( *Update:* I removed the actuall code, because the answer became a mini jQuery source code...)

```
// Handle when the DOM is ready
ready: function(wait) {
    ...

// Call all callbacks with the given context and arguments
fireWith: function(context, args) {
    ...

jQuery.Callbacks = function( flags ) {  
    ...

// The deferred used on DOM ready
readyList,
```

Check those functions and variables in the [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

Answer (score 2):

It wil run sequencially.

If one of the `init()`'s does an async call, that will obviously be async, but each function (or any line actually) will run in turn.